# Data frame creation from MAP of N elements with schemaDetails of N elements

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How do I convert the `input5` data format into DataFrame, using the schema details mentioned in `schemanames`?

The conversion should be dynamic without using `Row(r(0),r(1))` - the number of columns can increase or decrease in input and schema, hence the code should be dynamic.

```
case class Entry(schemaName: String, updType: String, ts: Long, row: Map[String, String])

val input5 = List(Entry("a","b",0,Map("col1 " -> "0000555", "ref" -> "2017-08-12 12:12:12.266528")))  

val schemanames= "col1,ref"
```

Target dataframe should be only from Map of input 5 (like `col1` and `ref`). There can be many other columns (like `col2`, `col3`...). If there are more columns in Map same columns would be mentioned in schema name.

Schema name variable should be used to create structure , input5.row(Map) should be data source ...as number of columns in schema name can be in 100's , same applies to data in Input5.row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work for any number of columns, as long as they're all Strings, and each `Entry` contains a map with values for *all* of these columns:

```
// split to column names:
val columns = schemanames.split(",")

// create the DataFrame schema with these columns (in that order)
val schema = StructType(columns.map(StructField(_, StringType)))

// convert input5 to Seq[Row], while selecting the values from "row" Map in same order of columns
val rows = input5.map(_.row)
  .map(valueMap => columns.map(valueMap.apply).toSeq)
  .map(Row.fromSeq)

// finally - create dataframe
val dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(rows), schema)
```

Comment: If this solves your issue, please accept the answer to let other readers know it.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through entries in `schemanames` (which are presumably selected keys in the Map based on your description) along with a UDF for Map manipulation to assemble the dataframe as shown below:

```
case class Entry(schemaName: String, updType: String, ts: Long, row: Map[String, String])

val input5 = List(
  Entry("a", "b", 0, Map("col1" -> "0000555", "ref" -> "2017-08-12 12:12:12.266528")),
  Entry("c", "b", 1, Map("col1" -> "0000444", "col2" -> "0000444", "ref" -> "2017-08-14 14:14:14.0")),
  Entry("a", "d", 0, Map("col2" -> "0000666", "ref" -> "2017-08-16 16:16:16.0")),
  Entry("e", "f", 0, Map("col1" -> "0000777", "ref" -> "2017-08-17 17:17:17.0", "others" -> "x"))
)  

val schemanames= "col1, ref"

// Create dataframe from input5
val df = input5.toDF

// A UDF to get column value from Map
def getColVal(c: String) = udf(
  (m: Map[String, String]) =>
     m.get(c).getOrElse("n/a")
)

// Add columns based on entries in schemanames
val df2 = schemanames.split(",").map(_.trim).
  foldLeft( df )(
    (acc, c) => acc.withColumn( c, getColVal(c)(df("row"))
  ))

val df3 = df2.select(cols.map(c => col(c)): _*)

df3.show(truncate=false)
+-------+--------------------------+
|col1   |ref                       |
+-------+--------------------------+
|0000555|2017-08-12 12:12:12.266528|
|0000444|2017-08-14 14:14:14.0     |
|n/a    |2017-08-16 16:16:16.0     |
|0000777|2017-08-17 17:17:17.0     |
+-------+--------------------------+
```